# How to correctly pronounce the major philosophers names?

Tags: reference-request

Or a link to somewhere that does. An audio recording of the orthoepy is ideal. I came to Kierkegaard, and don't trust youtube. Videolectures.net was searched; no results. 
How does one say other major philosophers such as Nietzsche, Kant...etc?

Comment: Sometimes you can get good results from [howjsay.com](http://www.howjsay.com) (beware: flash required) or [pronouncehow.com](http://www.pronouncehow.com). Example: "[Kant](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=kant)". IMO the former gives better results than the latter most of the times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a look at their wikipedia pages. There the names are spelled using the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA):

[image: Nietzsche]

For some entries there are even audio examples in ogg-format available:
[image: Kierkegaard]